# Having trouble with max and ceil PHP?

Tags: php

This might seem like a very simple thing, and maybe I'm just not understanding the question? Anyway. `$a` and `$b` are random numbers from 1000 to 10000. I need to take the largest one and round it to the nearest hundred. 
Is this supposed to be like so:

```
$a = 5;
$b = 10;
echo mt_rand($a,$b);
```

But then, how do I get the largest number and round it? 
I don't know why this confuses me so much. 
Also, apparently, I am supposed to use max somewhere.

Comment: Hint: try `$a = mt_rand(1000, 10000);`. Also,you will need to build an `if()` comparison and set `$c` to the larger variable. Once you have `$c` then you can round it.

Comment: Thank you. Gives me a starting point

Comment: @Anya tht is not a good method monkey is suggesting. It means you have to "if" every single value. My method below loops to create the random numbers. Another method is to create an range and shuffle it. See here https://3v4l.org/SmAYO this means there is no looping at all and it is probably faster if it's lots of numbers you need to create. For ten values, they are probably very close in memory and time. But if you loop, say 1000+ values then the one without loop is probably faster.

Comment: Andreas, I've found a way to do this without a loop (how it was supposed to be done, according to the assignment), after going over your answer. Here it is:   
 $a = rand(1000,10000);
 echo 'Random number: ' .  $a . '<br>';
 
 
 $b = rand(1000,10000);
 echo 'Random number: ' .   $b . '<br>';
 
 $c = max($a, $b);
 echo 'The largest of the two:  ' . ($c) . '<br>'; 
 
 echo 'Rounded ' . round($c/100)*100;

Comment: That only creates two random numbers. If that was the assignment I misunderstood it. Good that you completed the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the values to an array then use max of the array.
To round the value to closest 100 you need to use the following formula `round(x/100)*100`

This example makes 10 random numbers and echo the max value and the rounded max value.

```
For($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $a[] = mt_rand(1000,10000);
}
//Var_dump($a);
Echo max($a). "\n"; // max number

Echo round(max($a)/100)*100; //max number rounded
```

https://3v4l.org/NRWiH

Comment: Thank you so much.